# How can I run Google's apps without Google play services?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-maps, youtube, google-play-services

Most of the Google apps (nearly all) require Google play services to run, like YouTube.I never liked Google play services and play store but I've to keep them because I can't run gmail and YouTube without it. 
Is there any way to run those apps.
 without Google play services.

P.S.- Device is rooted,xposed  enabled, runs on CM12.1

Comment: I'm not entirely sure for all those GApps (I've banned them all), but take a look at [microG](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a), which is an open-source replacement to that. It's reported to work with Play Store, so it might work with other GApps as well.

Comment: @Izzy Seems wonderful.. Gonna try .. Thanks Buddy

Comment: It is – I'm running it on multiple devices :) Don't forget to come back and let us know whether it worked out with Gmail/YT (you know, you can always [answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Theirs a WebView Application that Sandboxes all of googles sites into one application called Gapps Browser
but this use the website versions...

Have you tried just saving bookmarks to the websites

I know xposed made a module to disable the google services warning, but it wrecked snap chat on my device !

MODULE LINK ADDED

[MODULE LINK http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/xeed.xposed.dngmod_v1_d32fa3.apk](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/xeed.xposed.dngmod_v1_d32fa3.apk)

[INFO LINK http://repo.xposed.info/module/xeed.xposed.dngmod](http://repo.xposed.info/module/xeed.xposed.dngmod)

Comment: Well I don't use snapchat so you can tell me that module's name

Comment: this app will run without google services

Comment: Thanks for the module link sir but it doesn't work with 5.0+

Comment: And no YouTube and gmail support

Comment: Try and get in contact with the development team, it could just be a simple rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Google apps usually require Google Play Services and Framework. If the Google apps have a web interface, then use that in a web browser.

Usually, the web interface detects that you are on Android and ask you to load the app. If your browser supports spoofing, that is if you pretend to be using IE/Firefox for desktop, then the redirection will not happen.

So, use a browser that supports useragent spoofing.